# Hiding labels in iOS without breaking the view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uilabel

I know we can use UIStackView in iOS9, but I'm not able to get rid of iOS8 at the moment, so I was wondering if is it possible to hide some labels inside a UIView (plain UIView, UIScrollView and UITableViewCell) and keep the rest of the visible labels "stacked".

Basically I've got some labels "stacked" vertically and pinned to each other by autolayout. If I hide any of them I get an empty space where the label was placed in interface builder.

Comment: Try to use for it content hugging priority and compression resistance. When you will set it right your label should make with zero height without the gap. Or you can use some components like this https://github.com/sobri909/MGBoxKit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to emulate the stackView's behavior using [OAStackview](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView), Following these steps:

- Subclass ViewController using a `UIScrollView` and a `OAStackView` property.
- Put the stack view inside the scroll view
- Set constraints for these properties programatically
- Add a bunch of custom labels to the stack view.